# sunburstR: Equal colors for each category

Tags: r, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

```
structure(list(Marketer = c("TASLOP YWORFYC", "YREVOCSID", "AKSLOP AJZIWELET", 
"AKSLOP AJZIWELET", "TASLOP YWORFYC", "SLUP AJZIWELET", "SGNIDLOH ITI", 
"DNALOP SKROWTEN AIDEM LANOITANRETNI MOCAIV", "YREVOCSID", "AKVATS", 
"YREVOCSID", "NOISIVELET SERUTCIP YNOS", "SLUP AJZIWELET", "AKSLOP AJZIWELET", 
"TASLOP YWORFYC", "DNALOP SLENNAHC LANOITANRETNI XOF", "YREVOCSID", 
"DNALOP SKROWTEN AIDEM LANOITANRETNI MOCAIV", "YREVOCSID", "TASLOP YWORFYC", 
"APURG MTA", "YREVOCSID", "AKSLOP AJZIWELET", "DNALOP SKROWTEN AIDEM LANOITANRETNI MOCAIV", 
"TASLOP YWORFYC", "DNALOP SKROWTEN AIDEM LANOITANRETNI MOCAIV", 
"YREVOCSID", "TASLOP YWORFYC", "AKSLOP AJZIWELET", "SGNIDLOH ITI", 
"SGNIDLOH ITI", "TASLOP YWORFYC", "SGNIDLOH ITI", "AKSLOP AJZIWELET", 
"SGNIDLOH ITI", "rehtO"), Advertiser = c("TASLOP", "NVT", "1 PVT", 
"2 PVT", "4 VT", "SLUP VT", "NVT", "NOEDOLEKCIN", "7 NVT", "VTT", 
"42 NVT", "NXA", "2 SLUP", "ELAIRES PVT", "2TASLOP", "LENNAHC CIHPARGOEG LANOITAN", 
"LENNAHC YREVOCSID", "LARTNEC YDEMOC", "ELYTS NVT", "VT OLOP", 
"AKWYRZOR MTA", "OBRUT NVT", "OFNI PVT", "VTM", "SWEN TASLOP", 
"cisuM VTM", "EFIL YREVOCSID", "EFAC TASLOP", "TROPS PVT", "42 NVT", 
"7 NVT", "TROPS TASLOP", "ELYTS NVT", "AINOLOP PVT", "OBRUT NVT", 
NA), size = c(634216983, 452207905, 219079142, 182359926, 78740169, 
64784549, 59142749, 57366881, 57262455, 56392788, 55692126, 53269413, 
50882084, 45753162, 39886956, 36180773, 35500223, 32739743, 30409799, 
27271797, 25305937, 20603791, 19771236, 16215889, 14897822, 14750001, 
13240967, 12872753, 12651485, 11188024, 11102314, 9553311, 5592035, 
4348638, 3638990, 53460983)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), vars = "Marketer", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    20L, c(0L, 4L, 14L, 19L, 24L, 27L, 31L), c(1L, 8L, 10L, 16L, 
    18L, 21L, 26L), 15L, c(6L, 29L, 30L, 32L, 34L), 35L, 11L, 
    9L, c(2L, 3L, 13L, 22L, 28L, 33L), c(5L, 12L), c(7L, 17L, 
    23L, 25L)), group_sizes = c(1L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
6L, 2L, 4L), biggest_group_size = 7L, labels = structure(list(
    Marketer = c("ATM GRUPA", "CYFROWY POLSAT", "DISCOVERY", 
    "FOX INTERNATIONAL CHANNELS POLAND", "ITI HOLDINGS", "Other", 
    "SONY PICTURES TELEVISION", "STAVKA", "TELEWIZJA POLSKA", 
    "TELEWIZJA PULS", "VIACOM INTERNATIONAL MEDIA NETWORKS POLAND"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L), vars = "Marketer", drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


library(d3r)
library(sunburstR)

color_palette <- list('#ff3e47','#d70f14','#7d0b0e','#969696','#6c6c6c','#434343','#a0cb0e','#64a505','#325005','#ffa441','#dc7300','#a03c00','#2cd5e6','#0a7db4','#05415a','#f00b69','#c30050','#640028')


sund2b(
    d3_nest(fr, value_cols = "size", root = "Marketer"),
    width="100%", colors = list(range = color_palette)
)
```

I have the following dataset which I cant to visualize using a Sunburst Chart from the sunburstR Package. It already works fine, but the different colors make it hard to interpretate.

What I want to is that for each categories on level 2, I want similar colors on level 3 to visually seperate the colors per category. Until now, the colors just get repeatet if necessary, which looks quite bad.

Does anyone know how to do that?

It should look like this:

http://bl.ocks.org/sathomas/4a3b74228d9cb11eb486

Comment: Looking [here](http://timelyportfolio.github.io/sunburstR/reference/sund2b.html) it seems you can put your own javascript color function, with `colors = htmlwidgets::JS("...")`.

Comment: yes, I already saw this. `JS("d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c)")` comes close to what I want, but these colors are not CI-conform with my company :-(